# Добавить значение переменной к строке

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть функция

```
$('.title_input').change(function(){

 text = $(this).val();

  clickId = this.id;

var myUrl = '/admin/basis/update/id/'+clickId;

      $.ajax({
            url: myUrl,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'text': text, 'id': clickId},

            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert('Сохранено!');

            },

            error: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert('ERROR!');

            }

        });
  });
```

Как заставить `.$ajax()` опцию `url:` съесть мою переменную `myUrl`?

Извиняюсь за вопрос. Вопрос не корректен все аякс нормально так ест.

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема? перед вызовом аякса добавьте console.log(clickId), чтобы убедится что ИД для каждого поля ввода установлен

Comment: Если перед вызовом аякса вывести алертом переменную myUrl, то в ней все будет норм, а вот аякс будет показывать не url: '/admin/basis/update/id/4', а url: myUrl,